# Nested If Not Working In Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Invested some time trying to resolve this and I really can not figure this out.

The formula always crashes in the false section of the `IF` statement. Creates a `#N/A!` in the cells.

Please advise what might resolve this.

```
=IF(AND(MATCH($H$1,$F$5:$F$22,0),$F5<=$H$1), 1, IF(AND(MATCH($H$1,$G$5:$G$22,0),$G5<=$H$1),true, false))
```

Comment: When you say MATCH, are you just trying to check whether the value in H1 is present in the cell range? (e.g. F5:F22 or G5:G22?)

Answer (score 0):

If MATCH() doesn't find anything, it will return #N/A, not FALSE. Try this instead:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($F$5:$F$22, $H$1)>0,$F5<=$H$1), 1, IF(AND(COUNTIF($G$5:$G$22,$H$1)>0,$G$5<=$H$1),true, false))
```

Comment: Also be aware that your formula returns 1, true, or false.

Comment: CountIf, that's an interesting way to do it. Why add the >0 after the countif though? It works without.

Comment: You can omit it if you like, I was just trying to make it clear what i was doing.